# Compare two arrays in LINQ query

Tags: postgresql, linq

I want to write LINQ query to compare two arrays.  I want the query to be translated to the following query:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM persons 
WHERE '{"dance", "acting", "games"}' && (hobbies);
```

That condition work in that way:

```
 '{"dance"}' && '{"dance", "acting", "games"}';  -- true
 '{"dance","singins"}' && '{"dance", "acting", "games"}';  -- true
 '{"singins"}' && '{"dance", "acting", "games"}';  -- false
```

I wrote this query:

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>(){ "dance", "acting", "games" };
var query = (from p in _context.Persons
             where arr.Any(kw => p.hobbies.Contains(kw))
             select new
                  {
                      id = p.id,
                      name = p.name
                  }).ToList();
```

The translated query is:

```
SELECT p."id" AS id, p."name" AS name 
FROM dataBase."Persons" AS p
```

It can understand that the filter performs in the server. so the query brings all the data from DB and filtered on the server. This causes to performance problems and not pass Load-Testing.

I need a query that will not only do the job but will also be translated to the above query with '&&'.

Is there any way in LINQ to execute this query?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using some version of [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx)? If so, would you be open to an answer which uses the SQL query that you have written?

Answer (score 0):

If your database looks similar like I am predicting this could be a solution. Some more code though but I think this should be executed as a SQL IN statement:

```
List<string> arr = new List<string>(){ "dance", "acting", "games" };

var matches = from hobby_person in _context.Hobbies_Persons
join person in _context.Persons on person.Id equals hobby_person.PersonId
join hobby in _context.Hobbies on hobby.Id equals hobby_person.HobbyId
where arr.Contains(hobby.Name) 
         select new
              {
                  id = p.id,
                  name = p.name
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: I saw now your were using postgresql, sorry about that, this was for sql server

Comment: Should be something similar though:http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/

Comment: I know I can solve this by creating a new table but that's not the solution I'm looking for.
Because I've already found a solution in Postgres. I just need to know if there is translation in LINQ